# Looping through dict elements in python

Tags: python

I have a piece of json which was converted to a dict using the json function.
From this:

```
{
    "imageIds": [
        {
            "imageTag": "1.2",
            "imageDigest": "sha256:8b67b1691b29e27a5ccbd6fea5c97c951a025ccd45b26d4c24567ca3c4c0f13b"
        },
        {
            "imageTag": "1.0",
            "imageDigest": "sha256:aa52a12bd6e516659452af5b9ed0fad8659f9e0cea6a986c6bfe02af388df189"
        }
    ]
}
```

To this:

```
>>> print data
{u'imageIds': [{u'imageTag': u'1.2', u'imageDigest': u'sha256:8b67b1691b29e27a5ccbd6fea5c97c951a025ccd45b26d4c24567ca3c4c0f13b'}, {u'imageTag': u'1.0', u'imageDigest': u'sha256:aa52a12bd6e516659452af5b9ed0fad8659f9e0cea6a986c6bfe02af388df189'}]}
```

In this example the number of keys (imageIds) is fixed but there could be any amount of imageTags under imageIds.

What I'm trying to do is loop through the 'imageTag' elements to read the tag number and perform an operation. If i wanted to loop through the key it seems straightforward with something simple like:

```
for key in data:
    print key, 'corresponds to', data[key]
```

However I'm uncertain on how I loop through the items under the key.
What I want to achieve is to print out:

```
1.2
1.0
```

Comment: `data[key][0]` gives you that inner dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over inner `dict` the same way you do for the outer one:

```
for key, value in data.iteritems():

    #now value can be a dictionary as well

    #for innerkey, innervalues in value[0].iteritems():
    #     print innerkey, innervalues

    #in order to only print the elements that have imageTag as the key, simply do:
    print value[0]['imageTag']
```

Comment: Thank you, that's close. How would I print out both imageTag's so that out put would be: 1.2, 1.0

Comment: Well, that´s just asking for the dictionary elements the key of which is "imageTag". See edited answer. This is very basic dictionary operations, I would recommend you that you spend half an hour reading about how they work.

Comment: Yes, proably a good idea. Thanks for the help.